# SICP Help me understand this

Tags: scheme, primes, sicp, factors, primality-test

The following program finds the smallest integral divisor (greater than 1) of a given number n. It does this in a straightforward way, by testing n for divisibility by successive integers starting with 2.

```
(define (smallest-divisor n)
  (find-divisor n 2))
(define (find-divisor n test-divisor)
  (cond ((> (square test-divisor) n) n)
        ((divides? test-divisor n) test-divisor)
        (else (find-divisor n (+ test-divisor 1)))))
(define (divides? a b)
  (= (remainder b a) 0))
```

We can test whether a number is prime as follows: n is prime if and only if n is its own smallest divisor.

```
(define (prime? n)
  (= n (smallest-divisor n)))
```

The end test for find-divisor is based on the fact that if n is not prime it must have a divisor less than or equal to n.44 This means that the algorithm need only test divisors between 1 and n. Consequently, the number of steps required to identify n as prime will have order of growth (n).

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 3):

Your last paragraph was copied with some errors. It's *sqrt(n)*, not *n*, which is obvious from reading the code.

To understand this code, you need to read it, *slowly*. The authors of the book wrote their code in this verbose manner specifically so that it can be read, slowly, in English, and *understood as it is being read*. That was their goal as far as I understand it.

Like so:

```
(define (smallest-divisor n)
  (find-divisor n 2))
```

We define smallest divisor of a number *n* to be the result of finding a divisor of *n* with a starting value of *2*. So we won't consider *1* as a number's divisor. So far so good.

```
(define (find-divisor n test-divisor)
```

Finding a divisor of a number *n* with a starting value of *test divisor* is done  by (well, we know we start with *2*; since it's an argument, this code is prepared to work with any value given to it... what are these values? for now we know that *2* is one possibility; let's hold this thought and re-examine it later):

```
  (cond ((> (square test-divisor) n) n)
```

1. First comparing the square of the *test divisor* with *n*, and in case the square is greater than *n*, return *n* as the result. We've found it!

   ```
       ((divides? test-divisor n) test-divisor)
   ```
2. If the previous test was unsuccessful, we next try testing whether *test divisor* divides *n*. If it does, we return the *test divisor* as the result. We've found it!

   ```
       (else (find-divisor n (+ test-divisor 1)))))
   ```
3. If all the previous tests failed, we come to the crux of the matter:

   - finding a divisor of a number *n* with a value of *test divisor* that didn't pan out **is the same as** finding a divisor of a number *n* with a starting value of *this test divisor value* ***plus 1*** !

   This just means in plain English, "let's try dividing *n* with the next testing number".

(.... so, what values are possible for *test divisor* to have, except *2*?)

```
(define (divides? a b)
  (= (remainder b a) 0))
```

can you finish it up now?

Comment: The function (find-divisor n test-divisor) is tail-recursive. This means, the algorithm is iterative. That is an improvement over an recursive algorthm.